# Android ScrollView doesnt work

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

[image: This is the problem]I'm trying to use scrollview in an app, but it doesn't work, the scroll bar doesn't appear and the buttons overlap, I'm using `RelativeLayout` to do this, I tried by other ways, but it doesn't work too.

Does someone know what I have to do?

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="81dp"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/Texto14"
                android:id="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="#333399"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="291dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
                android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                android:text="@string/Texto15"
                android:id="@+id/buttonIniciarConversaPerfilV"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="#333399"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="291dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Texto16"
                android:id="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="#333399"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonIniciarConversaPerfilV" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewPerfilV"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_below="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/Texto8"
                android:id="@+id/textViewNomePerfilV"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPerfilV"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/Texto9"
                android:id="@+id/textViewCursoPerfilV"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewNomePerfilV" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/Texto10"
                android:id="@+id/textViewDataPerfilV"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewCursoPerfilV"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Take `ScrollView` as `Parent`

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand

Comment: Remove main `RelativeLayout` and take `ScrollView` as Main Layout

Comment: First of all if your content fit on screen then no Scroll apply and you also you RelativeLayout child reference is not clear can you please post some image so from try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it. I just removed Parent Layout `RelativeLayout`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="81dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#333399"
            android:text="@string/Texto14"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonIniciarConversaPerfilV"
            android:layout_width="291dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:background="#333399"
            android:text="@string/Texto15"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
            android:layout_width="291dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonIniciarConversaPerfilV"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#333399"
            android:text="@string/Texto16"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPerfilV"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewNomePerfilV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPerfilV"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/Texto8"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCursoPerfilV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewNomePerfilV"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
            android:text="@string/Texto9"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDataPerfilV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewCursoPerfilV"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:text="@string/Texto10"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This works, but the scroll bar doesnt appear in my AVD

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `RelativeLayout` inside a `ScrollView` put the `RelativeLayout` inside a `LinearLayout`

Comment: @HareshChhelana you see the buttons overlapping because the RelativeLayout doesn't work into ScrollView

Comment: No this is not problem of RelativeLayout given reference is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Linearlayout>
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="81dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/Texto14"
            android:id="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#333399"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="291dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:text="@string/Texto15"
            android:id="@+id/buttonIniciarConversaPerfilV"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#333399"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="291dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Texto16"
            android:id="@+id/buttonIDAmizadePerfilV"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#333399"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonIniciarConversaPerfilV" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPerfilV"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/Texto8"
            android:id="@+id/textViewNomePerfilV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPerfilV"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/Texto9"
            android:id="@+id/textViewCursoPerfilV"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonHomePerfilV"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewNomePerfilV" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/Texto10"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDataPerfilV"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewCursoPerfilV"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

 </linearlayout>
</scrollview>
```